# Product code in WooCommerce renders wrong phone number

Tags: javascript, wordpress, woocommerce

My client needs a different phone number based on geolocation.

I had written this code:

```html
<a id="Call-us" href="tel:x.innerHTML"><Button class="nectar-button large regular extra-color-1 regular-button" onclick="getLocation()">CALL US</Button>
</a>
<script>
  var x = document.getElementById("Call-us");

  function getLocation() {
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
      navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(Call);
    } else {
      x.innerHTML = "+6492571212";
      return x.innerHTML;
    }
  }

  function Call() {
    x.innerHTML = "1300798747";
    return x.innerHTML;
  }
</script>
```

But the code gives the wrong output. Gives a call with the different phone number.